# Always get 504 unknown error after 30 seconds with delta list calendarView

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I use list calendarView with delta to track changes.

However, when there are many noEnd repeat events in Office365 calendar, the server always response 504 unknown error after 30 seconds until I decrease the maxpagesize and query time range.

It seems that the server doesn't receive the response from upstream server after waiting for 30 seconds, so return error to client.

However, this design is not friendly to client users.
We can NOT expect what maxpagesize and time range will not reach 504 unknown error before we send api.

Hope Microsoft can fix this bug or provide an recommended request parameters.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you get a 504 error code when the response entities has too many items.

Based on my test, it indeed returns a 504 Error. We can submit this issue to [the User Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) to help MS Graph developer team prioritize it over other investments.